# The method importTeams() is undefined for the type SchedulerOutput

Tags: java

I'm creating a scheduler in Java. I had everything inside in one class, but now I want to split it up into separate classes. It's quite small program, so there's likely little benefit, but I want to get the concepts of it correct. Code is below.

I'm getting an error in the second class on the importTeams() method. I thought that as long as I imported the package this method was in, it would be ok. Obviously not. Any tips?

```
package fifa.scheduler.fileimport;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import fifa.scheduler.output.*;

public class FileRead2 {

    private String rrTeam;

     public List<String> importTeams() {    
            ArrayList<String> teamList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            BufferedReader br = null; 
            int linecount = 0;  
            String teamcounter;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path")); 
                while (br.readLine() != null){
                    linecount ++;
                }
                br.close();
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path"));
                setRrTeam(br.readLine());
                while ((teamcounter = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    teamList.add(teamcounter);
                    }
                if (linecount % 2 != 0) {
                    teamList.add("byeteam");
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
            return teamList;
     }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            FileRead2 fr = new FileRead2();
            fr.PrintTeams();    
        }
        private void setRrTeam(String rrTeam) {
            this.rrTeam = rrTeam;
        }
        private String getRrTeam() {
            return rrTeam;
        }
}



package fifa.scheduler.output;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import fifa.scheduler.fileimport.FileRead2;

public class SchedulerOutput {
    public void PrintTeams(){

    List<String> teamList = importTeams();
     int tl = teamList.size();
     int bh = 0;
     int uh = (tl - 2);
     for (int i = 0; i <=(teamList.size()-1); i++) {     
     System.out.println("Week " + (i+1) + " fixtures");
     System.out.println(getRrTeam() + " vs " + teamList.get(tl -1));
     while ((bh <= (tl / 2)) && (uh >= ((tl / 2)))) {
         System.out.println(teamList.get(bh) + " vs " + teamList.get(uh));
         bh++;
         uh--;
     }
     Collections.rotate(teamList, 1);
     tl = teamList.size();
     bh = 0;
     uh = (tl - 2);
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import the class using `import` statement, only the class's interface is imported. In order to call member methods, you need an instance of the class.

In your case, you should create an object of type `FileRead2` to call the `importTeams()` method on it.

```
// Since FileRead2 has some member variable, you should also think about
// initializing it appropriately if it is needed by importTeams method.
FileRead2 fileRead2Obj = new FileRead2();
fileRead2Obj.importTeams();
```

Similarly, to call static methods, you need to qualify the method name with the class name (though Java 5+ allows static import of methods as well).

If `importTeams()` was static method, then you should call it as follows, after importing the class:

```
FileRead2.importTeams();
```

Comment: You mean something like this?

`FileRead2 fr = new FileRead2;`

That gives me an error too, saying it can't be resolved to a variable. I'm not calling a static method though am I? At least it's not declared as static?

Comment: @Killian, I didn't get your comment. I updated my message on what I meant.

Comment: I was missing the parentheses. I understand now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Killian, you forgot the braces around the class name when constructing the object. It should be `FileRead2 fr = new FileRead2();`